# How to write to Web.Config in Medium Trust?

Tags: c#, asp.net, medium-trust

Uploading my first decently sized web app to my shared host provided me with a fresh set of challenges, by which I mean, sleepless nights. The issue was that I had most certainly not developed my application for medium trust (or had any clue what that was.)

I mitigated all of the issues, save one.

I had written an installer for the admin to be able to specify their connection string and other preferences, but I cannot find a way to write to a web.config in medium trust. Does anyone have a solution, or should I just be putting preferences in another file?

Comment: One solution: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100307-1.aspx

Answer (score 24):

That actually sounds like IIS's `Low` level. If it is, then you won't be able to write to any file, not just the web.config.

Here are the levels from IIS's help file:

> - Full (internal) - Specifies unrestricted permissions. Grants the ASP.NET application permissions to access any resource that is subject to operating system security. All privileged operations are supported.
> - High (web_hightrust.config) - Specifies a high level of code access security, which means that the application cannot do any one of the following things by default:
>
>   - Call unmanaged code.
>   - Call serviced components.
>   - Write to the event log.
>   - Access Message Queuing service queues.
>   - Access ODBC, OleDb, or Oracle data sources.
> - Medium (web_mediumtrust.config) - Specifies a medium level of code access security, which means that, in addition to High Trust Level restrictions, the ASP.NET application cannot do any of the following things by default:
>
>   - Access files outside the application directory.
>   - Access the registry.
>   - Make network or Web service calls.
> - Low (web_lowtrust.config) - Specifies a low level of code access security, which means that, in addition to Medium Trust Level restrictions, the application cannot do any of the following things by default:
>
>   - Write to the file system.
>   - Call the Assert method.
> - Minimal (web_minimaltrust.config) - Specifies a minimal level of code access security, which means that the application has only execute permissions.

I would suggest that if you are dead set on having an installer, have it create a `web.config` in memory that the user can save locally and `FTP` up afterward.

Comment: This is how it works in Microsoft Web Installer when you dont set the write permissions on the web application folder.